# Read / Write special characters (like tilde, ñ,...) in a console application C

Tags: c, windows, locale, codeblocks, stdio

I'm trying that a C console application can read (using the keyboard) special Spanish characters such as accents, 'ñ', etc in a `scanf` or `gets` and then, print it too with `printf`.

I have achieved to show these characters correctly (stored in a variable or, directly, from `printf`) thanks to the package `locale.h`. I show an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Add languaje package
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[254];

    // Set languaje to Spanish
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");

    // Show correctly spanish special chars 
    printf("¡Success!. It is shown special chars like 'ñ' or 'á'.\n\n\n");

    // Gets special chars by keyboard
    printf("Input spanish special chars (such 'ñ'): ");
    gets(string);

    printf("Your string is: %s", string);

    return 0;   
}
```

but I have not yet achieved to pick them up correctly with the functions mentioned above.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you.

---

**EDIT 1:**

In testing, I observed that:

- **`setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");`** It shows the characters of the Spanish correctly, but it does not collect them from the keyboard.
- **`setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");`** It picks up the Spanish characters correctly from the keyboard, but it does not show them well.

---

**EDIT 2:**

I have tryed too `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`, `setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.UTF-8");` and `setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.ISO_8859-15");` with the same results as **EDIT 1** (or catch well characters from keyboard or show them well in console, but never both at the same time).

Comment: On what operating system? Did you read http://utf8everywhere.org/ ? You probably want (at least on Linux) `setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.UTF-8");` What terminal emulator? What font?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I believe you are right you should put this as an answer.

Comment: BTW, `gets` is obsolete and dangerous. Use `fgets`, `getline`, `readline`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes. I have tryed `setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.UTF-8");` and `setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.ISO_8859-15");` too but no they are not working too. I run C program with CodeBlocks, GCC Debugger, on Windows

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ok, I will take it in mind. For official project, I will use `fgets` instead of `gets`. Than you for the advice

Comment: Don't comment your own question, but **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: Ok. I will do that

Comment: You forgot to mention Windows in your question (at least as a tag), and CodeBlocks. BTW [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is a compiler (the debugger might be `gdb` )

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have modified question adding that tags that you advice me.

Comment: @eryksun I have tryed all you comment me in 1st message and continues not working. Now I will try to set `stdin` to `_O_U16TEXT`. Thank you for your advices. I will tell you if that works

Comment: Also, I have tryed `SetConsoleCP` to `UTF8`, `Unicode` and `ANSII` but did not work. Also I have tryed setting `stdin` and `stdout` to `_O_U8TEXT` or `_O_U16TEXT` and neither. Also include I do not like use `ReadConsoleW`. Thank you for the information

Comment: wow! `SetConsoleCP(1252)` and `SetConsoleOutputCP(1252)` works!! Thank you! and for Latin-15 there is any number? Post it as answer, I will choose it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft's C runtime library (CRT) does not support UTF-8 as the locale encoding. It only supports Windows codepages. Also, "es_ES" isn't a valid CRT locale string, so `setlocale` would fail, leaving you in the default C locale. Newer versions of Microsoft's CRT support Windows locale names such as "es-ES" (hyphen, not underscore). Otherwise the CRT uses the full names or the old 3-letter abbreviations, e.g. "spanish_spain", "esp_esp" or "esp_esp.1252".

But that's not the end of the story. When reading from and writing to the console using legacy text encodings instead of Unicode, there's another layer of translation in the console itself. To avoid mojibake, you have to set the console input and output codepages (i.e. `SetConsoleCP` and `SetConsoleOutputCP`) to match the locale codepage. If you're limited to Spanish or Latin-1, then it should work to set the locale to "spanish" and set the console codepages via `SetConsoleCP(1252)` and `SetConsoleOutputCP(1252)`. More generally you could look up the ANSI codepage for a given locale name, set the console codepages, and save them in order to reset the console at exit. For example:

```
wchar_t *locale_name = L"es-ES";
if (_wsetlocale(LC_ALL, locale_name)) {
    int codepage;
    gPrevConsoleCP = GetConsoleCP();
    if (gPrevConsoleCP) { // The process is attached to a console.
        gPrevConsoleOutputCP = GetConsoleOutputCP();
        if (GetLocaleInfoEx(locale_name, 
                            LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE | 
                            LOCALE_RETURN_NUMBER, 
                            (LPWSTR)&codepage, 
                            sizeof(codepage) / sizeof(wchar_t))) {
            if (!codepage) { // The locale doesn't have an ANSI codepage.
                codepage = GetACP();
            }
            SetConsoleCP(codepage);
            SetConsoleOutputCP(codepage);
            atexit(reset_console);
        }
    }
}
```

That said, when working with the console you will be better off in general if you set `stdin` and `stdout` to use `_O_U16TEXT` mode and use wide-character functions such as `fgetws` and `wprintf`. Ultimately, if supported by the C runtime library, this should use the wide-character console I/O functions `ReadConsoleW` and `WriteConsoleW`. The downside of using UTF-16 wide-character mode is that it would entail a complete rewrite of your code to use `wchar_t` strings and wide-character functions and also would require implementing adapters for libraries that work with multibyte encoded strings (preferably UTF-8).

Comment: Thank you so much. A very explained and concise answer.

Comment: Downvotes are useless without an explanation. How am I supposed to fix a problem if you don't tell me what the problem is? If I'm mistaken or have poorly explained something, I'm open to suggestions. If I'm outright wrong, I'll delete the answer without hesitation. I don't care about the points, just the quality of the answer.

Comment: I upvoted you, and I do not understand too why are downvoting you.  My suppose is that it could be due to in certain parts of the cole you need 'study and fix' it,  like last like `atexit(reset_console);`: for `reset_console` in Windows does not work good,  or is needed other library,  i do not know.  In line `gPrevConsoleCP = GetConsoleCP()` is needed init var like `int gPrevConsoleCP` and something more,  But I do not think it should be cause of downvoting without any explanation.  My advice is : revise code and update answer. People should upvote again. I hope it helps.

Comment: Also, I think that including `#include`'s necesary should helps. And if the code could be a MCVE then it is perfect (if with only copy and paste into IDE can be executed and see,  then,  how code works Will be the perfect answer)

Comment: I have openned a question for trying to solve errors in code posted in your answer, due to I have all day trying to make it works but I couldn't. Question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733087/debug-a-code-based-on-windows-set-locale-and-consolecp-and-make-it-run-get-erro/49734109#49734109. Can you answer it, please? Thank you.

Comment: @JuMoGar, it's just a code snippet to show one possible example of looking up the code page to set the console input and output code pages. It wasn't intended to be an MCVE. I assume the reader knows or can look up well-known functions such as C `atexit` and WinAPI `GetLocaleInfoEx`.  Also a lowercase "g" prefix is common for global variables. I assumed it would be clear that `gPrevConsoleCP` and `gPrevConsoleOutputCP` are global variables for use with an at-exit function named `reset_console`, which I didn't show because it wasn't intended to be a complete example.